# How to HTTPPost ASP.Net MVC 5 CheckBoxList to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, http-post

I am having trouble getting the values to post to my database table from a checkboxlist.  Here are my models:

```
public partial class SecurityChange_Access
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Access_Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public partial class Change
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Emp_FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string Emp_MangerEmail { get; set; }
    public string Emp_MirrorAccount { get; set; }
    public string Security_Change_Access { get; set; }

    public List<SecurityChange_Access> SecurityAccessList { get; set; }

    public bool addAccess { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChangeRadioList { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option for TestRadio")]
    public String ChangeRadio { get; set; }
}

public class bTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the HTTPGet and HTTPPost:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Change(Change change)
{   
    List<bTest> list = new List<bTest>();
    list.Add(new bTest() { ID = 1, Name = "Add Access" });
    list.Add(new bTest() { ID = 2, Name = "Remove Access" });
    list.Add(new bTest() { ID = 3, Name = "Change Access" });
    SelectList sl = new SelectList(list, "Name", "Name");
    change.ChangeRadioList = sl;

    List<ActiveDirectory> objadlist = (from data in       objentity.ActiveDirectories select data).ToList();
    ActiveDirectory objAD = new ActiveDirectory();
    objAD.displayName = "";
    objAD.mail = "";
    objAD.Id = 0;
    objadlist.Insert(0, objAD);
    SelectList objmodeldata = new SelectList(objadlist, "displayName", "displayName", 0);
    /*Assign value to model*/
    change.ADList = objmodeldata;

    change.SecurityAccessList = new List<SecurityChange_Access>();
    change.SecurityAccessList = BindSecurity();

    return View(change);
}

public List<SecurityChange_Access> BindSecurity()
{
    List<SecurityChange_Access> _objsecurity = (from data in _entities.SecurityChange_Access select data).ToList();
    return _objsecurity;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Change([Bind(Include = "ID, Emp_FirstName, Emp_LastName, Emp_Supervisor, Emp_MangerEmail, Emp_MirrorAccount, Security_Change_Access, Security_Access_To_1, Security_Access_To_2, Security_Access_To_3, Security_Access_To_4, Security_Access_To_5, Security_Access_To_6, Security_Access_To_7, Security_Access_To_8, Security_Access_To_9, Security_Access_To_10, Security_Access_To_Other, Security_Access_ADF_Mirror, Security_Access_JDE_Mirror, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_1, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_2, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_3, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_4, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_5, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_6, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_7, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_8, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_9, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_10, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_11, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_12, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_13, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_14, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_15, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_16, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_17, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_18, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_19, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_20, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_21, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_22, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_23, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_24, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_25, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_26, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_27, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_28, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_29, Security_Access_NetworkDrives_30, IT_Equipment_1, IT_Equipment_2, IT_Equipment_3, IT_Equipment_4, IT_Equipment_5, IT_Equipment_6, IT_Equipment_7, IT_Equipment_8, IT_Equipment_9, IT_Software_1, IT_Software_2, IT_Software_3, IT_Software_4, IT_Software_Other, IT_Media_1, IT_Media_2, IT_Media_3, IT_Media_Other, IT_Other_Equipment, Additional_Information")] Change change, int? id)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECTED COUNTRY :- ").AppendLine();
            foreach (var item in change.SecurityAccessList)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    sb.Append(item.Access_Name + ", ").AppendLine();
                    _entities.Changes.Add(change);
                    _entities.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Change");
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
         foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            //check the ErrorMessage property
        }
    }
    return View(change);
}
```

Here is the Razor code:

```
<table border="0" width="1000" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecurityAccessList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="200">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.SecurityAccessList[i].IsSelected)
                @Model.SecurityAccessList[i].Access_Name
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.SecurityAccessList[i].ID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.SecurityAccessList[i].Access_Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

In my HTTPGET I am binding my list but then I need to post my list on the checked values.  I am not sure how to go about doing this.  I am also having problems getting the checked list so it is comma separated.  I can't seem to find anything online that can help me with this.  I just can't seem to be able to post the data to the Security_Change_Access field.

Comment: try to initialize SecurityAccessList in your Change class like :

public partial class Change
{
public Change()
{
ChangeRadioList = new List<SecurityChange_Access>();

}
// rest of properties
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not pass a complex object as a parameter to a GET method. Properties that are complex objects or collections will not bind (they will be null), you may exceed the query string limit (crashing your app) and then there the ugly url it creates. Just initialize a new `Change` in the method, or pass an `ID` and get the `Change` based on the `ID`.

Your view code looks OK although I suggest you use a label associated with the checkbox and the hidden input for the `Access_Name` property seems unnecessary

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecurityAccessList.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SecurityAccessList[i].IsSelected)
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecurityAccessList[i].IsSelected, Model.SecurityAccessList[i].Access_Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecurityAccessList[i].ID)
}
```

which should generate html with name attribute like

```
<input type=checkbox" name="SecurityAccessList[0].IsSelected" ...>
<input type=checkbox" name="SecurityAccessList[1].IsSelected" ...>
```

Next, remove the (awful) `[Bind]` attribute. By default, all properties are bound, which seems to be what you want to do, but in fact you have excluded `SecurityAccessList` (I think - tl;dr ) and included a whole lot of 'properties' that don't even exist in your model (`Security_Access_To_1, Security_Access_To_2, .....`). If you ever find your self needing to use `[Bind(Include="..")]`, stop and use a view model to display/edit what you need instead.

The POST method should then correctly bind your model with `change.SecurityAccessList` containing the collection. Note I recommend you change your parameter to (say) `model`. In this case its OK, but there are plenty of question on SO about binding failing because the name of the parameter match the name of a model property.

Side notes:

The `List<bTest> list = new List<bTest>();` bit where you create a `SelectList` for what seems to be used in a radio button list seems odd. A select list is not even appropriate for that usage and in any case your not even using the `ID` property of `bTest`. It may just as well be

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Add Access", "Remove Access", "Change Access" });
```

which produces exactly the same result, although I suspect all you need is the property to be `List<string>`

Next the `ActiveDirectory objAD = new ActiveDirectory();` bit where your seem to be inserting a 'default' or `null` item for use in a select list is also wrong. Again the only property you use is `displayName` but in any case delete it and use the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts `optionLabel`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, Model.ADList, "-Please select-")
```

This adds a `null` option `<option value>-Please Select-</option>` which can be used in association with the `[Required]` attribute.

Finally there the code inside the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block which makes no sense. You don't even use the value of `sb` (not sure what its even for) and then your attempting to add the same instance of `change` into the database each time `IsSelected=true`, except that its only added once because as soon as it is added, you do a redirect.

Comment: Ok, I am able to retrieve my checkbox list but now I am having issues posting the comma separated values to a different table.  How can I go about doing this.  All I want is to post the data back to the Change Model in a column.  I seem to be having trouble understanding how to get the values to post back to the database.

Comment: That's easy enough to do, but the question is WHY? You should not be storing comma separated values in a data base to represent relationships (the only case where it would be applicable if you stored an `enum` value decorated with the `[Flags]` attribute). And then of course you would need to parse it back again when reading the data. It's a little hard to understand exactly what your doing with tos code but I suspect you need a table with fields for the `employeeID` and the `SecurityAccessListID` or `SecurityAccessListName`