# Connect button from view to function in controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button

I'm new in MVC and trying to create a site.

My main problem is that I need to activate a function in my controller after clicking a button on the view.

This is my code in the view for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Star and Role and Categories" onclick="CreateCategoriesID"/>
```

On the screen in created several checkboxes from list, this is their code:

```
@foreach (Movies.Models.Category cat in lst)
{
    @Html.CheckBox(cat.ID.ToString()); 
    @Html.Label(cat.Name);
    <br />
}
```

Each checkbox looks like that:

```
<input name="5" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

only their name is different.

In my controller function I need to see which checkbox is clicked, I tried that way:

```
public void CreateCategoriesID(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string catID = "";

    List<Category> lst = entities.Category.ToList();

    foreach (Category cat in lst)
    {
        Request[cat.ID.ToString()].ToString();
    } 
}
```

This is the function that the button should activate.

The list is equal to the checkboxs list.

Is it the way to get elements from the screen?

How can I check if a checkbox is clicked?

How do I connect the button in the view to the function in the controller?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `object sender, EventArgs args` ??  Are you *sure* this is MVC and not Web Forms?

Comment: `onclick="CreateCategoriesID"` calls a javascript function in your view. NOot a server method. And the server method you have shown is WebForms code, not MVC. You need a form, you need to generate controls that based on your model (which using a `foreach` loop will not do) and you need to post that to a controller method. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed webforms and MVC.

This:

```
public void CreateCategoriesID(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Should be something like

```
public void CreateCategoriesID(SomeModel model)
{
    // read categories from model, the model may be the categories themselves or a property of it dependent on your data structrue.
}
```

(Where the form sumbits to {Controller}/CreateCategoriesID)

For how to bind to checkbox lists -

- [How to httppost asp.net mvc 5 checkboxlist to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328303/how-to-httppost-asp-net-mvc-5-checkboxlist-to-database)
- [ASP NET MVC CheckBoxList Basic Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786243/ASP-NET-MVC-CheckBoxList-Basic-Implementation)